# Do I really have to accept answer when people think the answer is ok?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

Well I have added a question in StackOverflow: [How to make WebRTC peer server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549642/how-to-make-webrtc-peer-server).

And I think in deep it is an advanced question.  And I was imagining how great answer I will get.

What happened is that someone added **linked comment** (which is open source code).

And another user just added that **link** inside an answer, and he is wondering if I want that answer or I want something else (inside the answer post).

Well I didn't accept it .. but another user started asking me why I didn't accept the answer and what exactly I want .. and he wasted about 15-20 minutes of my time trying to explain to him what really I want.

Maybe my question was clear for me. But it was really annoying that much of commenting.

Do I have to accept that answer only cause other users think the answer is fine?

And what can I do in this situation?

Comment: Although you don't have to accept any answer if it is not helpful, I do think you should review and probably revise the question.  For example, you could link to the host site for WebRTC.  If the given answer is currently missing your point, you should consider how to make your point clearer, by adding comments to the answer explaining, or (probably better) by revising the question to indicate what you're after more clearly.  Maybe you should explain why Node-WebRTC is not what you want.

Comment: Note that you should realize that multiple people have had to expend time trying to work out what you want.  People have tried to help you.  You spent 15-20 minutes trying to explain (I don't see much evidence of that time, but I suspect that comments have been removed from the question).  But, if you had spent that time clarifying your question so that it was easier to understand what you're after, and maybe why the proposed solution is not what you need, then you'd be doing the whole world a favour. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  Remember, no-one has to spend any time answering your question.  No-one should have to spend time trying to understand what you're asking for.  Your question should make all that crystal clear from the outset.  If you find that the rest of the world doesn't understand what you're asking, please have the humility to realize that the problem could be yours, not theirs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't think the answer helps you, then don't accept it. You don't have to listen to what other people ask you to do in that regard.

Comment: I agree.  It's a trade-off, though.  If you praise a question in comments, people wonder why you haven't accepted it.  If you're too fussy about answers, people might ding the question a few points.  :>

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I think you meant "praise an answer"?